# Docker Container error when i run docker Run

Tags: java, docker, jar, dockerfile

i created a docker container for a simple java application .

creation of Docker image is correctely done .
when i run docker run i have some problem related to java , but the application work well when i run it using IntelliJ.

docker Errors :

> PS C:\Windows\system32> docker run testing
>       Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
>       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/JMSException
>               at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
>               at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
>               at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
>               at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
>               at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
>               at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.JMSException
>               at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>               at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>               ... 7 more

Dockerfile:

> ```
> FROM openjdk:8-jre
> COPY /target/application.jar /tmp/application.jar
> WORKDIR /tmp
> ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-cp", "application.jar", "Package.ClassWithMain"]
> ```

Thank you in advance,
Mondher

Comment: Forget about docker first. Can you try running your jar on your command line, without Intellij.
I have a doubt on how you have created your jar file. It might not have all runtime/dependencies required.

Answer (score 1):

You: COPY /target/application.jar /tmp/application.jar
Try: COPY . /usr/src/myapp

You: WORKDIR /tmp
Try: WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp

Look for its written, should help!

RUN javac Main.java
CMD ["java", "Main"]

Comment: i am copying the jar file that contain all classes of the application .
i think it will not help running only the Main.java because it's depend from other classes

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be that your jar is lacking certain dependencies. Intellij may have the required dependencies in the build path which is why your application runs from that environment. Are you using maven or a build tool to create the jar?

Comment: Hello ,

i am using Maven to build the project.

Comment: If you unzip your jar are you able to verify that all the required dependencies are available?

Comment: i unzipped the jar file i only find .class files ,  pom.xml and pom.properties